# Objective-C and Cocoa change title of the button with tag

Tags: objective-c, button, tags, sender

Can someone please tell me how can I change the title of the button ? I have 10 buttons with tags from 1 to 10 and I want to change the title of the clicked button when I click on it. It always change the title of the last button with tag 10.
Buttons are connected by this:

> @property (assign,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSButton *clickButton;

I also added synthesize in *.m file.
In *.m file I have:

> NSLog(@"Button pressed: %i", (int)[sender tag]);
>       [clickButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'o']];

The method is also connected to the button:

> - (IBAction)startGame:(id)sender;

I do not want to make switch or make 10 buttons with no tags. Can I do this by any function to directly show text on the button which is clicked ?

Comment: You have 10 buttons and you want to change the title of button that's clicked or want to change the title of the last button  ? What title you want to set to the clicked button ?

Comment: I want to change the title of the button which is clicked. All buttons are connected to one method and one property. The title could be a text like "I was clicked" or a char "X".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sender` argument to your `-startGame:` method will be the `NSButton` that was clicked. So you could just do this:

```
- (IBAction)startGame:(id)sender
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Title string"];
}
```

Comment: How can I send 'sender' to other method ?

Comment: `sender` is just an object (an `NSButton` in your case). You would pass it to another method just like any other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect all button action with same Action by doing so you well get the action at a common place with the clicked button object and by accessing the button you can change the title. :)

Comment: if you have any problem while changing use below code.                                  - (IBAction)startGame:(NSButton *)sender
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Title string"];
}